# NextJs next.config.js adding multiple module.exports

Tags: next.js

My next.config.js like:

```
module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer({
  swcMinify: true,
```

Just want to add this `withCss(withPurgeCss())`

But have no idea how can I add multiple wrappers?

Comment: Have you tried `module.exports = withBundleAnalyzer(withCss(withPurgeCss({..})));`

Answer (score 1):

You can install [next-compose-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/next-compose-plugins) and use multiple plugins with `withPlugins`

```js
const { withPlaiceholder } = require("@plaiceholder/next");
const withPlugins = require("next-compose-plugins");
const withBundleAnalyzer = require("@next/bundle-analyzer")({
  enabled: process.env.ANALYZE === "true",
});

const nextConfig = {
  ...global config
};

module.exports = withPlugins(
  [[withPlaiceholder], [withBundleAnalyzer], [..moere]],
  nextConfig
);
```